WebDAV Server in Go: Unable to Save Changes to Files Directly on Remote Server (Error 0x8007001F)
I have implemented a simple WebDAV server using the golang.org/x/net/webdav library. I have successfully mapped this WebDAV service as a remote disk on Windows, and operations such as uploading, deleting, moving, and copying files work as expected.
However, when I attempt to double-click and open a file from the remote WebDAV server in a client, modify its content, and then try to save the changes, the save operation fails. I have tested this on both Mac OS and Windows, and direct editing of files on the remote WebDAV server is not possible. On Windows, the error message I receive is 0x8007001F.
My Go version is 1.21. Could someone help me understand why I am unable to save changes to files directly on the remote WebDAV server, and how I might resolve this issue?
my code:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/pem"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/webdav"
    "io"
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var address, port, username, password, path, maxSize, extensions string
    var ssl, help bool
    flag.StringVar(&address, "address", "localhost", "Listening address")
    flag.StringVar(&port, "port", "8080", "Port to listen on")
    flag.StringVar(&username, "username", "", "Authentication username")
    flag.StringVar(&password, "password", "", "Authentication password")
    flag.StringVar(&path, "path", "./files", "WebDAV file storage path, leaving it empty will automatically generate a 'files' directory as the path")
    flag.StringVar(&extensions, "ext", "", "Allowed file extensions, comma-separated, e.g., \".pdf,.xlsx\"")
    flag.StringVar(&maxSize, "maxsize", "", "Maximum allowed file size for uploads, e.g., 10M, 2G")
    flag.BoolVar(&ssl, "ssl", false, "Enable SSL, if 'cert.pem' and 'key.pem' exist in the directory, they will be automatically referenced, otherwise a self-signed certificate will be generated")
    flag.BoolVar(&help, "help", false, "Display help information")
    flag.BoolVar(&help, "h", false, "Display help information")

    flag.Parse()
    // Check if the --help or -h flag is provided
    if help {
        flag.Usage()
        return
    }
    // If the password is empty, generate a random password and write it to a specific file
    // If username or password is not assigned, generate an 'auth.json' file locally with a username and password
    if username == "" || password == "" {
        authFilePath := filepath.Join("auth.json")
        if _, err := os.Stat(authFilePath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
            fmt.Println("Username or password is empty, generating a random password and writing it to 'auth.json'")
            // Generate a random password
            password = generateRandomPassword(10)
            authData := map[string]string{
                "username": "user",
                "password": password,
            }
            authJSON, err := json.MarshalIndent(authData, "", "  ")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to generate JSON: %v", err)
            }
            err = os.WriteFile(authFilePath, authJSON, 0644)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to write to 'auth.json' file: %v", err)
            }
        } else {
            // Read the 'auth.json' file
            authJSON, err := os.ReadFile(authFilePath)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to read 'auth.json' file: %v", err)
            }
            var authData map[string]string
            err = json.Unmarshal(authJSON, &authData)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to parse 'auth.json' file: %v", err)
            }
            fmt.Println("'auth.json' exists, reading login username and password from 'auth.json'")
            username = authData["username"]
            password = authData["password"]
        }
    }
    // Combine address and port
    listenAddress := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", address, port)

    // Validate and process the path
    absPath, err := validateAndNormalizePath(path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Path validation error: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Create WebDAV handler
    handler := &webdav.Handler{
        FileSystem: webdav.Dir(absPath),
        LockSystem: webdav.NewMemLS(),
    }
    // Parse the upload file size limit
    var maxUploadSize int64
    if maxSize != "" {
        maxUploadSize, err = parseMaxSize(maxSize)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("File size conversion error: %s\n", err)
            return
        }
    }

    // Parse allowed file extensions
    allowedExtensions := parseExtensions(extensions)

    // Create HTTP server and add basic authentication
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Check username and password
        user, pass, ok := r.BasicAuth()
        if !ok || user != username || pass != password {
            w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="Restricted"`)
            http.Error(w, "Unauthorized", http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
        // Check file extension
        if r.Method == "PUT" {
            filename := filepath.Base(r.URL.Path)
            ext := strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(filename))
            if (len(allowedExtensions) > 0 && !allowedExtensions[ext]) || isForbiddenFile(filename) {
                http.Error(w, "Unallowed file extension", http.StatusForbidden)
                return
            }
        }
        // Check if the user modifies the file extension to conform to the specification
        if r.Method == "MOVE" || r.Method == "COPY" {
            destination := r.Header.Get("Destination")
            if destination != "" {
                ext := strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(destination))
                if (len(allowedExtensions) > 0 && !allowedExtensions[ext]) || isForbiddenFile(destination) {
                    http.Error(w, "Unallowed file extension", http.StatusForbidden)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        // Limit upload file size
        if r.Method == "PUT" && maxUploadSize > 0 {
            // Get the expected entity length from the request header
            // The file management system on macOS will automatically add this header when connecting to the WebDAV server
            entitySizeStr := r.Header.Get("X-Expected-Entity-Length")
            if entitySizeStr == "" {
                // If this header is not present, use Content-Length
                entitySizeStr = r.Header.Get("Content-Length")
            }
            entitySize, _ := strconv.ParseInt(entitySizeStr, 10, 64)
            if entitySize > maxUploadSize {
                http.Error(w, "File exceeds size limit", http.StatusRequestEntityTooLarge)
                return
            }
            // Prevent the absence of both headers with size parameters
            bodySize, newBody, _ := getFileSize(r.Body)
            if bodySize > maxUploadSize {
                http.Error(w, "File exceeds size limit", http.StatusRequestEntityTooLarge)
                newBody = io.NopCloser(nil)
                return
            }
            r.Body = newBody
        }
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)

    })

    // Start HTTP server
    if ssl {
        // Check if the certificate files exist
        certFile := "cert.pem"
        keyFile := "key.pem"
        if _, err := os.Stat(certFile); os.IsNotExist(err) {
            // Generate a self-signed certificate
            cert, key, err := generateSelfSignedCert()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error generating self-signed certificate: %s\n", err)
                return
            }

            // Save the certificate and key to files
            if err := os.WriteFile(certFile, cert, 0600); err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error writing certificate file: %s\n", err)
                return
            }
            if err := os.WriteFile(keyFile, key, 0600); err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error writing key file: %s\n", err)
                return
            }
        }

        // Configure TLS
        tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
            MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12, // Minimum supported TLS 1.2
            MaxVersion: tls.VersionTLS13, // Maximum supported TLS 1.3
            CipherSuites: []uint16{
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            },
        }

        // Start HTTPS server
        server := &http.Server{
            Addr:      listenAddress,
            TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
        }

        fmt.Printf("Starting WebDAV service (SSL) %s File storage path: %s\n", listenAddress, absPath)
        if err := server.ListenAndServeTLS(certFile, keyFile); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error starting WebDAV service (SSL): %s\n", err)
        }
    } else {
        // Start HTTP server
        fmt.Printf("Starting WebDAV service %s File storage path: %s\n", listenAddress, absPath)
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(listenAddress, nil); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error starting WebDAV service: %s\n", err)
        }
    }
}

// Generate a random password
func generateRandomPassword(length int) string {
    charset := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    var password strings.Builder
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        randomIndex, _ := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(int64(len(charset))))
        password.WriteByte(charset[randomIndex.Int64()])
    }
    return password.String()
}

// Get the size of the body
func getFileSize(body io.ReadCloser) (int64, io.ReadCloser, error) {
    // Use io.TeeReader to copy the request body to a buffer and calculate its size
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    teeReader := io.TeeReader(body, &buf)
    size, err := io.Copy(&buf, teeReader)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading file size: ", err)
        return 0, nil, err
    }
    return size, io.NopCloser(&buf), nil
}

// Watch the directory and remove files that meet the conditions, remove macOS dirty data and files with 0 bytes
func watchDirectoryRemoveFile(dir string) {
    // Traverse the directory and remove files that meet the conditions
    err := filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !info.IsDir() {
            // Remove macOS dirty data files
            if strings.HasPrefix(info.Name(), "._") || info.Name() == ".DS_Store" || info.Size() == 0 {
                err := os.Remove(path)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            }
            // Remove files with dangerous suffixes
            if isForbiddenFile(info.Name()) {
                err := os.Remove(path)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error in working directory %s: %v\n", dir, err)
    }
}

// Parse the upload file size limit
func parseMaxSize(maxSize string) (int64, error) {
    var size int64
    var unit string

    // Use a regular expression to parse the size and unit
    _, err := fmt.Sscanf(maxSize, "%d%s", &size, &unit)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("Invalid maximum file size: %s", maxSize)
    }

    // Convert the unit to bytes
    switch strings.ToLower(unit) {
    case "g", "gb":
        size *= 1024 * 1024 * 1024
    case "m", "mb":
        size *= 1024 * 1024
    case "k", "kb":
        size *= 1024
    default:
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("Invalid unit: %s", unit)
    }

    return size, nil
}

// Check if the filename contains forbidden suffixes
func isForbiddenFile(filename string) bool {
    // Define a list of forbidden suffixes
    var forbiddenSuffixes = []string{
        // HTML suffixes
        "html", "htm", "shtml", "xhtml", "xht", "xhtm",
        // PHP related suffixes
        "php", "php5", "pht", "phtml", "shtml", "pwml", "phtm",
        // JSP related suffixes
        "jspx", "jsp", "jspf", "jspa", "jsw", "jsv", "jtml",
        // ASP related suffixes
        "asa", "asax", "cer", "cdx", "aspx", "ascx", "ashx", "asmx", "asp", "asp80", "asp81", "asp82", "asp83", "asp84", "asp85", "asp86", "asp87", "asp88", "asp89", "asp90",
        // Other dangerous suffixes
        "vbs", "asis", "sh", "bash", "csh", "ksh", "zsh", "reg", "cgi", "exe", "msi", "wsf", "hta", "cpl", "drv", "sys", "dll", "com", "bat", "pl", "cfc", "cfm", "ini",
    }
    // Check from the end of the filename
    parts := strings.Split(filename, ".")
    for i := len(parts) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        suffix := parts[i]
        for _, forbidden := range forbiddenSuffixes {
            if suffix == forbidden {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

// Parse allowed file extensions
func parseExtensions(extensions string) map[string]bool {
    extMap := make(map[string]bool)
    if extensions == "" {
        return extMap
    }
    extList := strings.Split(extensions, ",")
    for _, ext := range extList {
        ext = strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(ext))
        extMap[ext] = true
    }
    return extMap
}

// Generate a self-signed certificate
func generateSelfSignedCert() (certPEM, keyPEM []byte, err error) {
    // Generate an RSA key pair
    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("Error generating RSA key: %w", err)
    }

    // Create a certificate template
    template := x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: big.NewInt(1),
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            CommonName:         "localhost",
            Organization:       []string{"WebDAV"},
            OrganizationalUnit: []string{"Development"},
        },
        NotBefore: time.Now(),
        NotAfter:  time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 365 * 10),

        KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageKeyEncipherment | x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature,
        ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
    }

    // Generate a self-signed certificate
    certDER, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &template, &template, &key.PublicKey, key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("Error creating certificate: %w", err)
    }

    // Encode the certificate and key to PEM format
    certPEM = pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE", Bytes: certDER})
    keyPEM = pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key)})

    return certPEM, keyPEM, nil
}

// Validate and normalize the path
func validateAndNormalizePath(path string) (string, error) {
    // Get the current working directory
    wd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error getting current working directory: %w", err)
    }

    // Convert the relative path to an absolute path
    absPath, err := filepath.Abs(path)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error converting path to absolute path: %w", err)
    }
    // Ensure the path is a subdirectory of the current working directory
    if absPath == wd || !strings.HasPrefix(absPath, wd) {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("path must be a subdirectory of the current working directory")
    }
    // Check if the directory exists
    if _, err := os.Stat(absPath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        // Directory does not exist, create it
        err := os.Mkdir(absPath, 0777)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
    }
    return absPath, nil
}


which error are you getting and from where in the code?

@erik258 Not in the program, but in the Windows file management. I mapped WebDAV as a local disk.It's an error code given by Windows.

I think you need to implement the r.Methods for PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, LOCK and UNLOCK to edit files.

When I switch to a different WebDAV client, I can save the file normally.
In my question, I overlooked a crucial detail: the file I was editing was an MS Office Excel Xlsx file, and I could not save it.
If it was a normal txt file, it would save normally.
From the logs, it was observed that connecting to the remote WebDAV using the system's built-in file manager causes file locking issues.
However, using a third-party client did not encounter this problem, and remote file editing was completed normally.
Does anyone know the reason for this discrepancy?
I used the WebDAV Simple Server to log the events.
Simple webdav server code in Go
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "golang.org/x/net/webdav"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var address string
    flag.StringVar(&address, "a", "localhost:8080", "Address to listen to.")
    flag.Parse()

    handler := &webdav.Handler{
        FileSystem: webdav.Dir("."),
        LockSystem: webdav.NewMemLS(),
        Logger: func(r *http.Request, err error) {
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("WebDAV request error: %s %s: %s", r.Method, r.URL, err)
            } else {
                log.Printf("WebDAV request: %s %s", r.Method, r.URL)
            }
        },
    }

    http.ListenAndServe(address, handler)
}

RaiDrive (third-party client)
2024/11/18 11:05:06 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /
2024/11/18 11:05:06 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /
2024/11/18 11:05:06 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /
2024/11/18 11:05:06 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/
2024/11/18 11:05:11 WebDAV request error: PROPFIND /files/~$test.xlsx: stat files/~$test.xlsx: no such file or directory
2024/11/18 11:05:11 WebDAV request: PUT /files/~$test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:05:11 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~$test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:05:12 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/
2024/11/18 11:05:12 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request error: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP: stat files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP: no such file or directory
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PUT /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PUT /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: MOVE /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test~CBA55B.tmp
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test~CBA55B.tmp
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: MOVE /files/~tmp1731899120747263644.TMP
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test~CBA55B.tmp
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test~CBA55B.tmp
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: DELETE /files/test~CBA55B.tmp
2024/11/18 11:05:22 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:05:23 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/
2024/11/18 11:05:23 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/
2024/11/18 11:05:25 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/
2024/11/18 11:05:27 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/

Windows System File manage Client
2024/11/18 11:07:29 WebDAV request: GET /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:29 WebDAV request: LOCK /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:29 WebDAV request: UNLOCK /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:29 WebDAV request: LOCK /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:29 WebDAV request error: PROPFIND /files/~$test.xlsx: stat files/~$test.xlsx: no such file or directory
2024/11/18 11:07:29 WebDAV request: PUT /files/~$test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:29 WebDAV request: LOCK /files/~$test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:30 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /
2024/11/18 11:07:30 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /
2024/11/18 11:07:30 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /
2024/11/18 11:07:31 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/
2024/11/18 11:07:33 WebDAV request: UNLOCK /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:33 WebDAV request: LOCK /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:33 WebDAV request error: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899252478: stat files/~tmp1731899252478: no such file or directory
2024/11/18 11:07:33 WebDAV request error: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: stat files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: no such file or directory
2024/11/18 11:07:33 WebDAV request: PUT /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:33 WebDAV request: LOCK /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: PROPPATCH /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: UNLOCK /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: LOCK /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: GET /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: PROPPATCH /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: HEAD /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: PUT /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: PROPPATCH /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: UNLOCK /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: UNLOCK /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request error: PROPFIND /files/test~CDA8C5.tmp: stat files/test~CDA8C5.tmp: no such file or directory
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: LOCK /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: GET /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: PROPPATCH /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: MOVE /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request error: MOVE /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: MOVE /files/test~CDA8C5.tmp
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:34 WebDAV request error: LOCK /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request error: LOCK /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request: GET /files/test.xlsx
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request: PROPFIND /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request error: PROPPATCH /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request error: MOVE /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request error: MOVE /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request error: MOVE /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request error: MOVE /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request error: MOVE /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request error: DELETE /files/~tmp1731899252478525738.TMP: webdav: locked
2024/11/18 11:07:35 WebDAV request: LOCK /files/test.xlsx

